# How to make a shared element transition in website

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, frontend

I want to make a shared element transition(Android) in website like below image:

[image]

After click on the image, it will move smoothly from original position to center on screen and background will change to white color. How can I do this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution using vanilla javascript. It also works on reponsive website.

```js
const imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("img"),
  blurry = document.getElementById("blurry");
let isOpened = false, // if some image is opened
  openedImageIndex = -1; // image index in imgs array, which is currently opened

const closeModal = () => {
  isOpened = false;
  imgs[openedImageIndex].style.transform = "translate(0,0)"; // move image back to original position
  blurry.classList.toggle("display");
  setTimeout(() => (imgs[openedImageIndex].style.zIndex = "3"), 600);
};

//Close modal on scrolling event
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if (isOpened) {
    closeModal();
  }
});
//Close modal when click on outside image
blurry.addEventListener("click", () => {
  closeModal();
});

//If your page has more than one image
for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; ++i) {
  imgs[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (isOpened) {
      isOpened = false;
      this.style.transform = "translate(0,0)";
      blurry.classList.toggle("display");
      setTimeout(() => (this.style.zIndex = "3"), 600); //time should be greater than animation time duration in css
    } else {
      isOpened = true;
      openedImageIndex = i;
      const screenWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
        screenHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight,
        imgPos = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
        imgWidth = this.clientWidth,
        imgHeight = this.clientHeight;
      const imgTop = imgPos.top,
        imgLeft = imgPos.left;
      const req_top = (screenHeight - imgHeight) / 2 - imgTop, //required top, left value to make sure the image moves to center on screen
        req_left = (screenWidth - imgWidth) / 2 - imgLeft;

      this.style.transform = "translate(" + req_left + "px," + req_top + "px)";
      this.style.zIndex = "5";
      blurry.classList.toggle("display");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

p {
  color: white;
}

.shared-element-transition {
  width: 79vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.shared-element-transition p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.shared-element-transition img {
  cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;
  cursor: zoom-in;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
}

.shared-element-transition #blurry {
  cursor: -webkit-zoom-out;
  cursor: zoom-out;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #333333;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease, visibility 0.5s ease;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease, visibility 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.shared-element-transition #blurry.display {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="shared-element-transition">
        <div id="blurry"></div>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
            industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
            scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
            electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
            Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
            Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/600/400">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
            industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
            scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
            electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
            Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
            Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" alt="">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
            industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
            scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
            electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
            Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
            Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
            industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
            scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
            electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
            Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
            Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.media>img').click(function(){
  
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color:#fff;
  color: var(--color-gray-2);
  font: var(--font-body);
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

.post {
  margin-bottom: var(--unit-xxl);
}
.post + .post:before {
  content: "- { · · · } -";
  display: block;
  font: var(--font-text);
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50vw;
}

.post > * {
  width: 60vw;
  max-width: 892px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.post > * + * {
  margin-top: var(--unit-m);
}

.hero {
  margin-bottom: var(--unit-xl);
}

h1 {
  color: var(--color-white);
  font: var(--font-title-1);
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
  margin-top: var(--unit-xxl);
}
h2 {
  color: var(--color-white);
  font: var(--font-title-2);
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
h3 {
  font: var(--font-title-3);
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.post * + h2,
.post * + h3 {
  margin-top: var(--unit-xl); /* if it's not the first element */
}
.post h1 + h2,
.post h1 + h3,
.post h2 + h3 {
  margin-top: 0; /* if it's like a tagline */
}

.post h1 + h3 + * {
  margin-top: var(--unit-xl); /* this indicates the header */
}

p {
  font: var(--font-text);
}

ul {
  font: var(--font-text);
  list-style: inside;
}

a {
  color: var(--color-gray-4);
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: var(--color-white);
}

.post figcaption {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: var(--unit-xxs);
}

.post img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  transition:all 0.3s ease;
}


.media {
  margin-top: var(--unit-xl);
  margin-bottom: var(--unit-xl);
}
img.open{
transform:scale(1.4);
box-shadow:0 0 0 2000px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
.media > * {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="post">

  <p>The date is October 1st, 2015. For the last 3 hours, I've been researching as much as I can about Mars occasionally stopping to drool over those beautiful red-tinted landscapes. I'm working on an email campaign titled Add Mars to your travel bucket-list - funny for a designer at <a href="booking.com">Booking.com</a>, <em>"Planet Earth's #1 Accommodation Site"</em>.</p>
 
  <div class="media">
    <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*BEEp4hungBtNQslF-UwKzw.png" />
    
  </div>

   
  </div>
  <p>These places are scattered all over the globe, some only 3 hours away from our office here in Amsterdam.</p>
  <p>Once the list was complete, we took the idea to our copywriters and they eagerly jumped on board. After that, all we needed was a back-end developer and 14 hours later we'd created an email and <a href="https://dribbble.com/shots/2299776-Get-ready-for-the-Final-Frontier">this landing page</a> from scratch.</p>
 
</article>
```

Comment: In your solution, the image does not move from original position to center on screen. It just scales at its position. Not what I'm talking about